# Как получить содержимое файла с помощью curl

Tags: curl, php

Имеется следующий запрос, но он не возвращает содержимое файлика из данного урла, что тут можно исправить?

```
$ch = curl_init('https://www.aaramshop.com/api/api.php?data=products');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

var_dump($result);
```

Comment: У Вас рабочий скрипт. Может быть на во время тестирования был недоступен url.

Comment: url доступен, но там что-то типа с ssl сертификатом, и еще если в браузере перейти по этому урлу то он загружается на сохранение.

Comment: Я в ответ на использование ващего сприпта получил строку в формате JSON след вида - string(1500380) "[{"0":"22","id":"22","1":"Kissan Mixed Fruit Jam","product_name":"Kissan Mixed Fruit Jam","2":"Kissan-Mixed-Fruit-Jam-500g-AaramShop.jpg"......

Comment: да, на сервере работает, а вот на денвере не работает. В принципе на денвере только лишь тестировал так что и не обязательно

Answer (score 1):

```
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url );

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
        'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    ));

    $html = curl_exec ($ch);
    //$responseInfo = curl_getinfo($ch);
    curl_close ($ch);
```